# Can't seem to add a user to AD security group via checkedlistbox in Windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I can't get a part of my windows form functioning. I don't know where I have gone wrong because many other sources have said to add users to groups this way. I get this error everytime:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Unspecified error'

It fails on this line here: `de.Properties["member"].Add(up);`

But I can't figure out why it is failing. I have also tried with `string group = chklbADGroups.CheckedItems` to no avail, which is why I tried specifying the group name instead.

```
        foreach (string item in chklbADGroups.Items)
        {
            string group = "CN=mygroup";
            bool isChecked = chklbADGroups.GetItemChecked(chklbADGroups.FindStringExact(item));
            string LDAP = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
            PrincipalContext ouContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, LDAP);
            WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            SearchResult results;
            DirectorySearcher ds = null;
            DirectoryEntry de = new
            DirectoryEntry(ouContext + group);
            
            UserPrincipal up = new UserPrincipal(ouContext);

            if (de != null && isChecked == true)
            {
          
                de.Properties["member"].Add(up);
                de.CommitChanges();
                de.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I actually figured it out. I worked around it using a different method. Instead of using a foreach loop that looped through every item that was checked in the checklist. (I kept getting an error that the list had changed and couldn't be looped through a second time.) I used a foreach loop that loops through all checked items and then puts those into strings and puts them in a list.
Then I used a foreach that loops through that list (Which doesn't change) and gets the strings from the list and passes them to the group principal via the GroupName variable.

```
            var checkedItems = new List<string>();
            foreach (var chk in chklbADGroups.CheckedItems)
            {
                checkedItems.Add(chk.ToString());
            }
            foreach (string GroupName in checkedItems)
            {
                
                    WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
                    string username = up.SamAccountName;
                    MessageBox.Show(GroupName);
                    PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DomainName);
                    GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Name, GroupName);
                    if (GroupName != null)
                    {
                        grp.Members.Add(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
                        grp.Save();
                        grp.Dispose();
                        context.Dispose();
                    }
            }
```